# Scripting s series of camera shooting with different aperture and focal length

Tags: canon, software, focal-length, remote, eos-utility

Is there any software, app, or any way that I can script a series of photo shooting with Canon camera with different aperture and focal length?

Something like

Things I tried
DSLR Controller App
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.dslrcontroller
This doesn't seem to have any scripting system

EOS Utility and DigiCamControll
They don't let me change the focal length by script

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the focal length by script because AFAIK there are no DSLR lenses wit an electric zoom, so the camera itself cannot control the zoom. You would need an external rig with a motor to rotate the zoom ring on the lens, and control that motor from the same script that controls the other parameters.

Comment: It seems canon has an 18-135mm lens that comes with just such an optional accessory....

Comment: I have a lens with autofocus, which allows DigiCamControll Software to change the focal length by clicking. So I'm sure there is a way to control it, but I don't know how to script it.

Comment: Autofocus!=Focal length, Focal length=zoom.